# Adjusted /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ir file

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I want to config my /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ir file to be like Windows keyboard layout. Is there a provided config for it?
[This](https://gist.github.com/sijad/d63afe9c2955ad87e91792a9ea97ae19) is an example for my request, but it's a 'like Mac keyboard layout' config not 'like Windows keyboard layout'.

Comment: Hi Reza, I am not sure what you mean by "like windows" layout. Can you be more specific of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @MarceloAvila Hi. I want a file to config keyboard layout (place of characters in keyboard) like windows' keyboard layout. For example in windows, [this](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+060C) char is in 'Y' key place.

Comment: Windows doesn't have a fixed layout for all countries and languages, it is a software setting. Also, the physical keyboard also differs in different locations. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout. If you can specify exactly which physical keyboard you have and which layout you would like to achieve, I am sure you will be able to get an answer.

Comment: to be more precise, the `y` key in my keyboard might be a in different place than in yours. Try adding  a screenshot or an image of the desired layout.